# "Feature detection" let me down. A case for browser detection or is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, browser-detection

I have read many posts here and on other sites regarding browser-detection vs. feature-detection, and I understand all of the pros of feature-detection. However, I have hit an issue in which browser detection might be the right answer. Testing my site's HTML5 implementation in Safari compared to other browsers, I am horrified at the load times. For a particular page I tested with HTML5 video, here are the load times:

Chrome: 4 secs.
Firefox: 3 secs.
IE9: 4 secs.
Safari 5.1.7 (for PC, tried three times): 1m 12s, 1m 4s, 1m 3s, 57s (?!?!)

I tried to find any reasonable explanations, as many others have observed the same problem in Safari (at least v. 5.1.7), but none has emerged that I could find. Even though Safari technically "supports" HTML5, I can't in good conscience leave it like this for my viewers. I already have code and media to serve Flash video via SWFOBJECT for browsers that don't support HTML5 (triggered via "canPlayType" JS check). I'm open to other suggestions, but at this point it seems I need to specifically serve the Flash video for Safari users too. I've never written/tested browser detection code, and I know it's a hinky process. So if that's the best route, what would be the best JavaScript code for this? If there's a better solution I should be considering, then by all means pass it along!

Here is the dynamic HTML that my JS serves for HTML5 video capable browsers:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="David Kinsey" name="author">
    <meta content="David Kinsey" name="designer">
    <meta content="general" name="rating">
    <meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots">

    <title>David Kinsey: Volleyball Scorekeeping Assessment Demo</title>

    <!-- global stylesheets -->
    <link href="/css/layers.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/nav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- scaleSWF css
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/scaleSWF.css" /> -->

    <script src="/javascript/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/genVideo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body id="defaultBody">

    <!-- create top banner full-width of page -->
    <div id="banner_top">
        <script src="/javascript/genHeader.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div id="banner_bar"></div><img alt="Banner graphic of my name, David Kinsey" src="/images/bannerMyName.png" id="banner_myname"><a href="http://www.davidkinsey.me/index.htm" class="noOutline" id="homeLink"><img "="" alt="Logo of my initials, DLK" src="/images/DLKlogo-SMALL.png" class="noOutline" id="DLKlogo"></a><img alt="Banner graphic of my title, Instructional Designer" src="/images/instructDesigner.png" id="banner_title">
    </div>

    <video width="826" height="616" id="videoTag" preload="auto" controls="controls" poster="/images/logoAnimationStill.png" class="centeredMedia" autoplay="true" tabindex="0" style="visibility: visible;">
        <source src="http://www.davidkinsey.me/video/demoAssessment.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        <source src="http://www.davidkinsey.me/video/demoAssessment.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the dynamic alternative HTML for SWFOBJECT Flash video:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="David Kinsey" name="author">
    <meta content="David Kinsey" name="designer">
    <meta content="general" name="rating">
    <meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots">

    <title>David Kinsey: Volleyball Scorekeeping Assessment Demo</title>

    <!-- global stylesheets -->
    <link href="/css/layers.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/nav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- scaleSWF css
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/scaleSWF.css" /> -->

    <script src="/javascript/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascript/genVideo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body id="defaultBody">

    <!-- create top banner full-width of page -->
    <div id="banner_top">
        <script src="/javascript/genHeader.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div id="banner_bar"></div><img alt="Banner graphic of my name, David Kinsey" src="/images/bannerMyName.png" id="banner_myname"><a href="http://www.davidkinsey.me/index.htm" class="noOutline" id="homeLink"><img "="" alt="Logo of my initials, DLK" src="/images/DLKlogo-SMALL.png" class="noOutline" id="DLKlogo"></a><img alt="Banner graphic of my title, Instructional Designer" src="/images/instructDesigner.png" id="banner_title">
    </div>

    <object width="805.2389380530973" height="616" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="demoAssessment_controller.swf" id="flashcontent" style="visibility: visible;" class="centeredMedia" autoplay="true">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="333333">
        <param name="quality" value="best">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
        <param name="flashvars" value="csConfigFile=demoAssessment_config.xml&amp;csColor=333333&amp;csPreloader=demoAssessment_preload.swf&amp;csFilesetBookmark=0">
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the relevant JavaScript code:

```
function addVideoSources(pageName, vid) {

    var newMP4 = document.createElement("source");
    var newWebm = document.createElement("source");

    newMP4.setAttribute("src", containerID + pageName + ".mp4");
    newMP4.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4");
    newWebm.setAttribute("src", containerID + pageName + ".webm");
    newWebm.setAttribute("type", "video/webm");

    vid.appendChild(newMP4);
    vid.appendChild(newWebm);   
}

function addVideoAttributes(pageName, vid) {

    vid.setAttribute("id", "videoTag"); 
    vid.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    vid.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    vid.setAttribute("poster", "/images/logoAnimationStill.png");

    if (pageName != "index") {
        vid.setAttribute("class", "centeredMedia"); 
        vid.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");       
    } else {
        vid.setAttribute("class", "rightSideMedia");    
    }

    vid.addEventListener('loadstart', loadstarted, false);
    vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',
        function() { 

            if (document.getElementById("noJavaScript")) {
                obj = document.getElementById("noJavaScript");
                obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
            }

            sizeVideo(pageName, this, this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight, this.offsetTop);

        }, false);
    vid.addEventListener('error', failed, false);
}

function appendVideoObj(vidObj) {

    var contentCol = document.getElementById("contentCol");

    if (contentCol) {
        contentCol.insertBefore(vidObj, contentCol.firstChild);
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(vidObj);
    }
}

function insertHTML5Video() {

    var newVid = document.createElement("video");
    var pageName = getPageName();

    addVideoAttributes(pageName, newVid);
    addVideoSources(pageName, newVid);
    appendVideoObj(newVid);
}

function swfObjectLoadedHandler(e) {
//  alert("e.success = " + e.success +"\ne.id = "+ e.id +"\ne.ref = "+ e.ref);

    var obj = new Object();
    var pageName = getPageName();

    if (pageName != "index") {
        e.ref.setAttribute("class", "centeredMedia");   
        e.ref.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");     
    } else {
        e.ref.setAttribute("class", "rightSideMedia");  
    }

    if (e.success) {
        if (document.getElementById("noJavaScript")) {
            obj = document.getElementById("noJavaScript");
            obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
        }
        sizeVideo(pageName, e.ref, e.ref.width, e.ref.height, e.ref.offsetTop);
    } else {
        obj = document.getElementById("videoLayer");
        alert("Movie load failed. Please try again by refreshing your browser.");
    }
}

function insertSWFobject() {

    var flashcontent = document.createElement("div");
    var req = swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9.0.115");
    var bookmark = args.movie ? args.movie : 0;
    var pageName = getPageName();

    var cs_noexpressUpdate = document.createElement("div");
    var noFlashPlayerPara = document.createElement("p");
    var noFlashPlayerText1 = document.createTextNode("I'm sorry, but the video content for this page requires Adobe Flash Player® version 9 or higher to be installed on your computer. You can download the latest version of Flash Player® for free by visiting ");
    var flashPlayerLink = document.createElement("a");
    var noFlashPlayerLinkText = document.createTextNode("Adobe's Flash Player® download page");
    var noFlashPlayerText2 = document.createTextNode('. If you have the player installed, verify that your browser has JavaScript enabled. You can find easy-to-follow instructions how to do this by using Google® with the words "enable JavaScript" in the search box. Thank you!');

    flashcontent.setAttribute("id", "flashcontent");
    flashcontent.setAttribute("class", "noJavaScript");
    appendVideoObj(flashcontent);

    if (req ) {
        swfobject.embedSWF(pageName + "_controller.swf", "flashcontent", vidSpecs[pageName].width, vidSpecs[pageName].height, "9.0.115", null, { csConfigFile: pageName + "_config.xml", csColor: "333333", csPreloader: pageName + "_preload.swf", csFilesetBookmark: bookmark }, { bgcolor: "333333", quality: "best", allowscriptaccess: "always" }, null, swfObjectLoadedHandler );
    } else {
        flashPlayerLink.setAttribute("href", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer");
        flashPlayerLink.appendChild(noFlashPlayerLinkText);
        noFlashPlayerPara.setAttribute("class","noFlashPlayerText");
        noFlashPlayerPara.appendChild(noFlashPlayerText1);
        noFlashPlayerPara.appendChild(flashPlayerLink);
        noFlashPlayerPara.appendChild(noFlashPlayerText2);
        flashcontent.appendChild(noFlashPlayerPara);
    }
}

function getClientWidth() {
    return document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && !window.opera?document.documentElement.clientWidth:document.body.clientWidth;
} 

function getClientHeight() {
    return document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && !window.opera?document.documentElement.clientHeight:document.body.clientHeight; 
}

function onloadHandler() { 

    var obj = document.getElementById("noJavaScript");
    var vidElem = document.createElement("video");

    getBrowserInfo();
    obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);

    if ((vidElem.canPlayType) && uaNotSafari()) {       //  if browser has HTML5 video support and is NOT CRAPFARI use HTML5 video
        insertHTML5Video()
    } else {        // no video tag support; use SWFobject
        insertSWFobject();                                          // otherwise use Flash video via SWFOBJECT
    }

}   /* END onloadHandler */

addLoadEvent(onloadHandler);        // requires global.js to be included in same document
```

Thanks,
- DK

Comment: Probably would be easier to just point you to the live site which has the markup and client-side code: http://www.davidkinsey.me/flash/scoringCourseAssessment/demoAssessment.htm (the html is created via DOM scripting in the JS file genVideo.js)

Comment: @ user: Here's why you need to post it **in the question**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Hi T.J. (et al), sorry I did not have the code inserted and formatted properly. It was not laziness, I just didn't realize, even having read the FAQs. I edited the original post with all of the related code. Hopefully my code overall meets with general approval, as there are great programmers on this site. Thanks again for any assistance you can provide - I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to detect browser.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
if (ua.indexOf('safari')!=-1){ 
  if(ua.indexOf('chrome')  > -1){
     alert("1") // chrome
  }else{
     alert("2") // saf
   }
}
```

Comment: The question isn't "how do I detect the browser," it's "Is there a way to feature-detect this rather than browser-detecting?"

Comment: Hi, after adding the code in as directed I have not seen any responses. I wanted to add a note to my original question, instead of asking it again, to see if anybody can offer input. Thanks!